# Can I mass deselect check-boxes by certain criteria? This deselects all "jQuery('input').prop('checked', false);"

Tags: javascript, jquery

But is there a way I can deselect by certain criteria? In the example below I want to only deselect names that start with A

```
[X] Alan
[] Mark
[x] Andrew
```

Comment: Please post HTML, not just some text. You likely want `$("input:checkbox[name^=A]").prop("checked",false);`

Comment: You can use any criteria you like.  The first step would be to actually look at your HTML and see how you can distinguish the target elements from the non-target elements.  (And if you can't, then you may need to add something to the HTML, such as `data-*` attributes, to help you distinguish them from each other.)

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

you can use startsWith() method and iterate every checkbox, this can be usefull if you need to perform, lets say, to lowercase convertion

The HTML

```
<input id="ch1" type="checkbox" value="Alan" checked>
<label for="ch1">Alan</label>
<input id="ch2" type="checkbox" value="mark" checked>
<label for="ch2">Mark</label>
<input id="ch3" type="checkbox" value="andrew" checked>
<label for="ch3">Andrew</label>

<br>
<button>Uncheck a*</button>
```

and the JS

```
$('button').on('click',function(){

  $('[type="checkbox"]').each(function()     {
       if($(this).val().toLowerCase().startsWith('a')){
         $(this).prop('checked',false)
       }
   });
});
```

And a working Example
https://codepen.io/Teobis/pen/YvaoJL?editors=1011

Hope this helps

Comment: This will also check all checkboxes with a value that does not start with `a`, and not only uncheck those starting with `a`.

Comment: you are totally right @t.niese, edited, i need to pay more atention

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has a selector that selects attributes starting with a certain value by putting `^` after the attribute name:

```
     $("input[name^='A']").prop('checked', false);
```